# Fastest possible Apple Style Flip Counter in native code on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es, core-graphics

I'd like to mimic an Apple style flip counter on iOS.

Specifically, this thing is going to be FLYING FAST.  It's not going to be an alarm clock, think player high-score where you are racking up points chunks at a time.  The counter may jump from 0 to 100, to 5000, it will not increment sequentially, but when it does increment it will animate to the next number at a nice clip and it's going to be jumping to the next target value in a second or two.  It will not have a set number of digit places either, it can count from 0 to 2,000,000 if it wanted to.  Like a player high-score, you don't know what they will end up getting.  Since it can't be negative, theoretically maximum would be `UINT_MAX`

I did some searching, and I found a couple of great resources, neither of which seems to me like the correct approach.

This is a js/css approach the theoretically could run inside a UIWebView:

- http://cnanney.com/journal/code/apple-style-counter-revisited/

And this article explains how to do page turning in Core Animation.  It's detailed enough, but it seems to me like it's missing some key components, and would cause touches to get ignored on the UI while it's flipping.

- https://web.archive.org/web/20150321200917/https://www.voyce.com/index.php/2010/04/10/creating-an-ipad-flip-clock-with-core-animation

Now, after reading these I've got some different ideas on how to do it on my own, trying to weigh the pluses and minuses of each approach:

1) Load up the html counter whole-sale in the UIWebView.

- Apparent benefits: possibly tons of code reuse, quick and dirty
- Apparent downsides: the overhead of a `UIWebView` and constant calls to `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` from the host app which has the next number just seems silly

2) Create a custom sprite sheet and use core animation

- Apparent benefits: native code, seems like it would be a less fugly approach than using the web view
- Apparent downsides: creating a custom sprite sheets at this point seems a bit pointless in the face of custom drawing since I'm already creating a view with custom drawing anyway.  Seems like the only way to get it to perform well would be to draw images to sublayers rather than using UIImageViews

3) Render text/rounded rects with Core Graphics

- Apparent benefits: 100% native code solution, no images
- Apparent downsides: boatloads more code that having some UIImage instances.  Don't really know if I can get the right look I'm after without the images

4) Render the whole thing with OpenGL ES 2.0

- Apparent benefits: complete control over rendering, possibly best performance
- Apparent downsides: seems to me like I would still probably need some images to bind to textures, probably piles more code than core graphics rendering in #3

On the one hand, I can rationalize it and say the animation is only going to last a half a second or a second, so the best thing to do is to just fake it somehow with blurry images and not actually animate anything.  On the other hand it seems to me this is precisely what Core Animation + Core Graphics was designed to do well, and I ought to use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ended up doing the drawing with images using image sprites.

code here
https://github.com/reklis/flipcounter

Comment: I have determined this is *not* the fastest possible way.  The better way is to have a single image and shift the bounds.  I have not had time to implement that.

Answer (score 1):

[image][screen short show both image view from right to left original and from left most re-size image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1g0R.png)    flipCounter work good in Xcode but there is one issue the issue is how i re-size  the FlipCounter View. when i change the original image with small image tis work not good.![this image 50% smaller then original image][2] 
i am waiting for Positive Reply.
Thanks advane

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand this.  Could you explain more about the  issue?

Comment: sir actually pink and blue are original size image (both work well )...but when i use (small image) re-size these image these tutorial no work well. i am using this tutorial https://github.com/reklis/flipcounter

Comment: you will need to adjust the image size in the #defines here https://raw.github.com/reklis/flipcounter/master/FlipCounter/FlipCounterView.m

Comment: Thanks For Reply. sir when i do changes in #defines it only changes in Frame. there is no Changes on image. Image are in original Frame size. Half image show when i do adjustment in #defines...Thanks Sir for given time...

Comment: Sawan, you need make new images if you want them smaller.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I'd go the core graphics route and just draw the text into the view in the drawrect method. I'd probably construct some kind of background and foreground images that I can overlay the text with to achieve the UIPickerView look. Since you'd only really have to animate the text, you could probably overlay some kind of semi-transparent gradient image that will make it look like the numbers are flipping around and going into shadow.

The OpenGL route seems a bit excessive if you're not programming the game in OpenGL. (plus you'll have to write a bunch of boilerplate code to render text and load images into textures, etc.)